# Angular $routeChangeSuccess - race condition depending on controller definition?

Tags: angularjs

I'm listening to $routeChangeSuccess inside a controller:

```
// In MyController
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", (a, b, c) => {
            console.log(a, b, c);
});
```

This works fine when the route changes as a result of navigation within the app, but not always when going directly to a URL in the browser e.g. /my-new-url

Performance depends on where the controller is defined:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController"></div>
```

If this is in the main index.html, it seems to work every time, however:

```
<mydirective ng-controller="MyController"></mydirective>
```

with:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: '<SOME_CONTENT>'
  }
});
```

or indeed:

```
<mydirective></mydirective>
```

and :

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    controller: "MyController",
    templateUrl: '<SOME_CONTENT>'
  }
});
```

These latter two only hear the $routeChangeSuccess about 50% of the time - presumably due to some compile/digest race condition.

I would much prefer to set my contoller in the directive definition - it's neater, seems nicely modular, and there's no superfluous markup. Unfortunately, it just doesn't work very often.

As a side note: why do I want to do this?

I'm struggling with an app design pattern that Angular seems to refuse to play ball with - I have a number of separate modules within my app, they're all alive at the same time, and I want them to respond to URL changes in an appropriate way.

I don't really understand why this is so hard to achieve. $routeProvider isn't of much use, because I can only have one view/controller per route - that's great if I want to build a Single Page Website, but not if I'm trying to build a Single Page Application with a complex UI. The ui-router plugin isn't really what I'm looking for either - it's more about states with optional routes.

This is the web - the URL is sacred! I want to honour it and use it as much as possible, and I want every component or module in my app to know what it's supposed to do based on the URL. I'm not sure why that's so hard with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

For any component to catch an event, that component must be loaded in the memory when the even is raised.

If you have used `ng-view`'s and controller\directives are defined as partials that load in `ng-view`, then it is too late for you to subscribe and listen to the event. The controller that loads when partials are loaded inside `ng-view` is not ready to handle the event by the time it is raised.

Anything outside the `ng-view` is global in nature and can always subscribe to such events.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm starting to understand the reasons for my problem. Am I thinking about my app structure wrong?  Can you suggest a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Whatever is loaded inside `ng-view` can be considered having a lifetime of  the route it is dependent on. If you have number of modules that are alive,  they cannot be view related. These can be services n all. Maybe a concrete example from you can help.